# Schedule a executable file without Windows task scheduler

Tags: java, windows

Is it possible to schedule a executable file to run just before log-off using java?
I am working on a application that needed to send a message to the sever just before the system log-off/shutdown. But I didn't find any method to solve it. If anyone know plz help me.

Thanks in advnce.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @TikkaBhuna Windows XP.

Comment: This is not possible. Such events as OS session open/close are OS specific and cannot be detected in a portable manner in Java.

Comment: [ShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) is probably what you need.

Comment: @fge According to the documentation I posted above the jvm is going to exit with logoff and a ShutdownHook should be executed then.

Comment: @user1232141 good point... That's a workaround, yes -- provided the JVM does not exit for one reason or another _before_ the user logs out ;)

Comment: @fge Yes, the JVM could still be killed. I don't know any better solution though.

Comment: @user1232141 I only need to send a simple string to a specified open port. Since I am new to Java I dont know how to use ShutdownHook. Can you give me a sample code. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments a ShutdownHook is probably what you are searching for.
Short example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  @Override 
  public void run() {
    // Code to be executed when JVM exits
    System.out.println("JVM exit");
  }
});
```

Note that the ShutdownHook will execute whenever the JVM exits. So it will also execute when your program terminates normally.

If you have any further questions comment on this answer.